# Error running unstack.sh

Tags: openstack, devstack

i have been using `OpenStack` through `DevStack` . Got this **error** when i try to run **unstack.sh**

```
viknesh@viknesh-HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC:/devstack$ ./unstack.sh   
* Stopping web server apache2             
apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using         127.0.0.1 for ServerName  
... waiting .                                                           [ OK ]
tgt stop/waiting  
Volume group "stack-volumes" not found  
Skipping volume group stack-volumes  
Volume group "stack-volumes" not found  
Skipping volume group stack-volumes  
viknesh@viknesh-HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC:/devstack$
```

Even i can't login to openstack dashboard from localhost using default username and password as admin and password

```
An error occurred authenticating. Please try again later.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want log in to the dashboard you should run stack.sh again. unstack.sh is for shutting down devstack and not for starting it!
The shell output you posted doesn't really show errors these are rather warnings.

Comment: ya i know i should use stack.sh to run . Just posted here to show the warning . The main problem is i cant login to dashboard after running stack.sh

Comment: Does stack.sh complete successfully? Like `stack.sh completed in x seconds.` When not where does it stop? If it completes without errors you should enable logging in your localrc 
`LOGFILE=/opt/stack/logs/stack.sh.log` 
`VERBOSE=True`
and check the log files. Keep in mind to login to the dahsboard with the same password which is in localrc.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues.  I traced it to my DHCP changing the IP for the machine. I had to change the IP in local.conf and run stack.sh